# Ionic AngularFireDatabase saying not authorized even though rules are open

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, angularfire2

#### Overview

**I am attempting to get data from a firebase database but it is saying I do not have permission, even though the rules are totally open.**

I started building this current implementation by following [this youtube tutorial](https://youtu.be/I_73tsvj6OI). After running into errors with the deprecated FirebaseListObservable, I changed my provider according to [this update information](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/version-5-upgrade.md#updating-firebaselistobservable-to-angularfirelistt). I also tried using the default open Firebase rules as well as the ones they recommend for "Allow All" in [the Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started?authuser=0).

#### Provider

[image: provider code]

#### Error Message

[image: Error Message]

#### Firebase Rules

The default open version of the rules, which also didn't work, had the line as `allow read, write;`

[image: Firebase Rules]

#### Database

[image: The Data]

#### Other possibly-relevant info

In the same way as can be seen [1 minute into the mentioned youtube tutorial](https://youtu.be/I_73tsvj6OI?t=1m), I am calling `initializeApp(firebaseConfig)` in the imports of my app.module.ts using the information from clicking "Add Firebase to your web app"

I am using `angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.8.0` which I installed with `npm install angularfire2`. When I ran `npm list` just now it gave me the following two warnings, which may be relevant to the issue. I'm using `@angular/common@5.2.10` and `@angular/core@5.2.10`

> npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/common@^6.0.0, required by angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.8.0
>   npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@^6.0.0, required by angularfire2@5.0.0-rc.8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution

The issue was that within the Firebase dashboard I was configuring the `Cloud Firestore (BETA)` database as opposed to the `Realtime Database` database. After switching to using the proper database and setting the rules I was able to get the data from both Storage and Realtime Database using the basic firebase library (didn't need angularfire2).

#### Working Code Example

In this example I get a snapshot of the root node and then, based off the key of that node, iterate through snapshots of each child node and store the `.val()` into the associated array. (note: the layout of the data in the new database is different from the format in the screenshot from the question)

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
...
guardiansList: any = [];
warriorsList: any = [];
prayersList: any = [];
...
    try {
        firebase.database().ref().once('value', (snapshot) => {
            snapshot.forEach((categorySnap) => {

                switch (categorySnap.key) {
                    case "guardians":
                        categorySnap.forEach((imgSnap) => {
                            this.guardiansList.push(imgSnap.val());
                            return false;
                        });
                        break;
                    case "warriors":
                        categorySnap.forEach((imgSnap) => {
                            this.warriorsList.push(imgSnap.val());
                            return false;
                        });
                        break;
                    case "prayers":
                        categorySnap.forEach((imgSnap) => {
                            this.prayersList.push(imgSnap.val());
                            return false;
                        });
                        break;
                    default:
                        console.log("Found Unknown Key");
                        break;
                }

                return false;
            });
        });
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
```

Comment: I am leaving the question unresolved in hopes that someone posts an answer that successfully uses the new `Cloud Firestore BETA`

Answer (score 1):

As @brenthompson2 mentions, I share the method using Firestore(beta) instead

in app.module.ts

```
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from 'angularfire2/firestore';

...
@ngModule({
...
imports: [
...
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment),
    AngularFirestoreModule,
  ],
})
```

and in any angular module or injectables

```
  constructor(private store:AngularFirestore) {

  }
  ...

  this.store.doc<any>(`users/${uid}`).snapshotChanges().subscribe(
    data=>{console.log(data.payload.data())}
  );
```

Not that different to firebase2/database